# What is difference between spend and social_spend in Facebook Ads API?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Working with the Facebook Marketing API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.7

[image]

What is the difference between spend and social_spend?

I assume that spend would be total, and social spend out be a subset of that spend. I have search, and read and googled and can't find a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that social_spend is a subset of 'spend'.

'spend' is the total you have spent on the object you're querying.

social_spend is the subset of that where the budget went towards stories due to people liking/commenting/sharing on the object. For example, you may have seen a video on your news feed that only showed up because one of your friends liked it. The social_spend by the owner of that video would increase.